# Seeing 'couldn't fetch versions' error with actions on google 'gactions' cli tool

Tags: actions-on-google

```
gactions list --project $PROJECT
```

I get a "couldn't fetch versions - requested entity was not found" error.

I'm able to update the actions package just fine - just not use list (and therefore I can't get/test as I don't know the version id). The action works fine on my Google Home and in the simulator.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

#### Console log:

```
gactions --verbose list --project $PROJECT

Checking for updates...
Successfully fetched update metadata
Finished checking for updates -- no updates available
Reading credentials from: creds.data
GET /v2/agents/XXXXXXXXXXX/versions?pageSize=10 HTTP/1.1
Host: actions.googleapis.com
User-Agent: Gactions-CLI/2.1.3 (darwin; amd64; stable/dff629ae63fd0bXXXXXXXXXXXXX4524569714e6)
Accept-Encoding: gzip


ERROR: Couldn't fetch versions
ERROR: Requested entity was not found.
2018/02/26 17:40:51 Server did not return HTTP 200
```

Unfortunately as the source isn't available online I'm unable to debug this myself to see what http response is being returned.

Comment: Did you write `gactions --verbose list --project $PROJECT` in your terminal?  `$PROJECT` is supposed to correspond to your project id.

Comment: Hi @NickFelker. No I've got it defined in the environment variable PROJECT. I can run 'gactions update' and 'gactions test' just fine and speak to my test app. I just can 'gactions list' for some reason!

Comment: @mleonard FWIW, using your command line and my project ID I get exactly the same result up to the time stamp and nonce/GUID-ish thing

Comment: Thanks @WilliamDePalo that's interest. I guess that suggests it's a bug with the cli or the server-side code on google's side rather than something I've done wrong.

Comment: Could you verify that your project indeed has more than just a DRAFT version? You should see the versions of your project listed at the bottom of the Overview page of the Actions Console (console.actions.google.com). Note that projects which have been submitted for review will not have versions (they are only a DRAFT version).

Comment: @SachitMishra My project just has a DRAFT version, as I haven't submitted it for review yet.

Comment: @mleonard How did you generate creds.data file ?

Answer (score 0):

The list endpoint doesn't return anything if the application is just a DRAFT and has no versions created yet.

However, if someone is looking for a way to pull the action-package of their project while it's in draft mode, among other information, I stumbled across a way to do that which isn't in the CLI(thanks a lot, google).

```
curl 'https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/agents/<YOUR_PROJECT_ID_HERE>/?access_token=<YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE>' -H 'authority: actions.googleapis.com'
```

The access token is the same one in `creds.data` if you've authorized with the CLI.

Comment: How to generate creds.data file?